# unsure of errors in angularjs unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

i am trying to unit test a controller in AngularJs and i am following the AngularJs docs as a guide. `https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller`

in the guide (in the link above) they have this code in the controller

```
$scope.spice = "habanero";
```

and this code in the test

```
it('should set the default value of spice', function() {
      expect($scope.spice).toBe('habanero');
    });
```

in the controller i am testing there is some code like this:

```
$scope.sessionViewModel = session;
```

and in my test i have written this:

```
it('should set the default value of sessionViewModel', function(){
            expect($scope.sessionViewModel).toBe(session);
        });
```

yet i am getting an error saying `TypeError cannot read property 'sessionViewModel' of undefined`

not really sure what i have done wrong

entire test file:

```
describe('forgotPasswordCtrl function', function() {

    describe('forgotPasswordCtrl', function(){
    var $scope;
    var returnMsg = 'Forgot password response message';
    var returnMsgTwo = '/web/tfgm_customer';

    beforeEach(module('forgotPasswordApp'));


    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = ('ForgotPasswordCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
            }));


        it('returns a -forgot password response- message', function(){
            expect($scope.globalError).toEqual(returnMsg);
        });

        it('assigns a url depending on a customer match happens', function(){
            expect(window.location.assign).toEqual(returnMsgTwo);
            });

        it('should set the default value of sessionViewModel', function(){
            expect($scope.sessionViewModel).toBe(session);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: That error is saying that $scope is not defined. Could you post your entire test file?

Comment: @SoroushHakami yep, done/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
    $controller = ('ForgotPasswordCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
```

to

```
    controller = $controller('ForgotPasswordCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
```

Comment: yes i did this and it altered nothing...
does any of the other code need changing? should this now work in your view?

Comment: Hm, not sure. If you can create a live demo of your test using Jsfiddle.net for example, I can take another look